# Why the methods of the Object Constructor do not work on DOM Elements

Tags: javascript

```
//------------
let person = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 22
}

let e = document.getElementById('task-title');

/* Object.getOwnPropertyNames()
Returns an array containing the names of all of the given object's own enumerable and 
non-enumerable properties. */

console.log(typeof person, person);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(person));

console.log(typeof e);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e));
console.dir(e);
```

For my custom person object the methods Object.getOwnPropertyNames works however it does not work the Element Object Why ?

&

Are the DOM Element Objects any different than a custom object? If yes How?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work?"

Comment: console.dir(e) successfully displays the list of the properties of the DOM Element, however Object.getOwnPropertyNames which is supposed to return an array of all properties returns empty array when I console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e));

Comment: If I understand [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) correctly, that's because Object doesn't have any intrinsic property names of its own.  Person does; you described them at the top of your post.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get my head around it. The article says "All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object; all objects inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype, although they may be overridden." Can you please elaborate and explain further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document.getElementById` return an `Element` object which has a `Node` as its prototype. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns an array of the *own* and *enumerable* properties of an object, that meaning that it does not include the properties *inherited* by that object.

For example:

```
function A(){
    this.propA = 'propA';
}

function B(){
    A.call(this);
    this.propB = 'propB';
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A);

var obj = new B();
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) // ["propB"];
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) // ["propA"];
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was a real eye opener. 
Now I understand that elements inside the DOM do not have methods or properties of their own instead they inherit from multiple objects Example(HTMLDivElement, HTMLElement and many more) 
I realized this when I tested getOwnPropertyNames(Element.__proto__)  then I started getting the properties and methods that were shown in the log by console.dir(Element) by chaining __proto__ multiple times.
And lastly I understood the actual use of console.log and console.dir.
Thanks a bunch